# How can I use Aggregate Operators in Linq queries with multiple tables?

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I would like to realize below the codes in T-SQL to Linq queries,

```
select rg.Name, Sum(si.TotalPoint) / Count(si.TotalPoint) from ScoreItem si    
inner join Score s on s.Id = si.ScoreId
inner join ProjectResearchGroup prg on prg.Id = si.ProjectResearchGroupId
inner join RgClone rg on rg.Id = prg.RgCloneId
where rg.Name in (N'26 Gros Kurşun Kalem Stant Skor Kartı'
--,N'A5/A6 Ayaklı Defter Stant Skor Kartı'
--,N'A5/A6 Defter Stant Skor Kartı'
--,N'Adel Metal Stant Skor Kartı')
group by rg.Name
order by Name
```

Then I have re-wrote them in Linq because I have to use it with EF,

```
(from si in ScoreItem
       join s in Score on si.ScoreId equals s.Id
       join prg in ProjectResearchGroup on si.ProjectResearchGroupId equals prg.Id
       join rg in RgClone on prg.RgCloneId equals rg.Id 
       group rg by rg.Name into g 
   select new {Name = g.Key, SISScore = g.Sum(rg.TotalPoint) / g.Count(rg.TotalPoint) })
```

But I have some problems, so if you have any advice, please feel to free and share with me,

Comment: `Some problems` is not descriptive at all! What kind of issue do you have? What's wrong with above Linq query? Please, be more specific.

Comment: In SQL: `Sum(si.TotalPoint) / Count(si.TotalPoint)` but in Linq: `g.Sum(rg.TotalPoint) / g.Count(rg.TotalPoint)`. You're getting data from different tables...

Comment: Simply, I would like to calculate  TotalPoint from ScoreItem table, with some where clause, it's a little bit difficult to explain, clearly I need to convert my sql statement to linq queries but when I have wrote my linq queries on LİnqPad4 then I met this error, 'the name 'ng' does not exist in the current context'.  but it's exist already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read my comments to the question. I think you should correct your query this way:

```
select new {Name = g.Key, SISScore = g.Average(x=>x.TotalPoint) })
```

because `SUM(Field)/Count(Field)` means you want to get **average** ;)

Comment: thanks dude, but, I need to find all Totalpoint's  Average, so first of all I have to  calculate all si.TotalPoint's sums then make average to result,